# Do I need to install Python if I already have the Anaconda distribution installed and want to use other text editors?

Tags: python, anaconda, python-install

I am new to Python and programming in general and have been using Spyder IDE from the Anaconda distribution for the past few months on Windows 10. It has been really simple and easy to download and use, and I can run all of my code within the IDE, so it has easy for me to begin learning Python.

I have now become more interested in Python and learning to code and am looking to try other text editors like VS Code or Sublime Text. I was wondering, however, if I need to download and install python to be able to run my code in a terminal or will my current Anaconda install be fine to run the code?

If I do need to download Python, will there be any conflicts by having Anaconda installed?

Sorry if I've used the wrong terminology or it's not clear.

Comment: You don't need to install Python again.

Answer (score 3):

No, anaconda downloads the python interpreter/compiler as apart of the package. But if you want to check to make sure, check your python version in the command line (here's a walkthrough on how to do that: https://blog.finxter.com/how-to-check-your-python-version/)

Also, if you did have it downloaded and re-downloaded python again, there wouldn't be any adverse effects. At worst it overwrites your original python file (which isn't a big deal considering they contain the exact same thing) and at best you'll update your version of python.

VS Code or Sublime Text will work fine for editing and running scripts, but are not required. Anaconda comes with the Spyder IDE.

Answer (score 0):

The answer for you will be No.

if you already had anaconda installed in your laptop, once you open it up you will realized you can install Python within the software.

Anaconda will not only included Python, R also will be included.

Spider or Jupiter notebook can be used for edit your Python scripts.