# After Anaconda installation, python gets recognized in cmd launched by Anaconda Navigator only - Does it mean python can be used within Anaconda?

Tags: python, anaconda, python-install

Learning from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61665557/do-i-need-to-install-python-if-i-already-have-the-anaconda-distribution-installe#:%7E:text=You%20don%27t%20need%20to%20install%20Python%20again.) , I understand that installing Anaconda on Windows 10 PC will automatically install Python compiler, so we don't need to install Python separately after we install Anaconda. Sounds good.

I install Anaconda and then start the Navigator.
Then I launch CMD.exe from Anaconda Navigator and type `python --version` to check the python compiler installed on my machine. So far so good.

[image: CMD from Anaconda]

Then I start CMD.exe manually from windows 10 as Administrator (Click Start --> Type CMD manually --> Right Click --> Run as Administrator).
Then I type `python --version` , it shows "Not Found".

[image: Not Found]

Does it mean that when installing Anaconda , Python is available only within Anaconda platform? Not globally anywhere within the Windows OS ?

Comment: Maybe the path to `python` is not added to systemwise `PATH` variable? Try finding the installation path of `python` and manually adding it to `PATH` system variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is only an issue of how `PATH` is set. Note how there is an additional `(base)` prepended to the `C:\>....` prompt. This indicates that a `conda` environment is currently `active`, which is what you are currently referring to as being "inside of anaconda". But more correctly, you should think of it like: I have a `cmd` prompt and the `conda` base environment is currently active.

When you run `cmd` from anaconda navigator, this get's done automatically. When you launch it by just starting `cmd.exe`, then this does not get done automatically. This behaviour could be influenced by checking the `Add Anaconda to PATH` during the installation.

To get a `cmd` prompt with the `(base)` environment active, you can do different things:

1. Start `cmd` from your anaconda navigator (as you have done so far)
2. Start the `Anaconda Command Prompt`, which you can find through hitting the windows key and then start typing the name
3. Start a normal `cmd` and then execute `<CONDA Install Dir>\Scripts\activate.bat`